# css3 background-size transition animation in Webkit doesn't work... Bug? Or wrong syntax?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Animating the background-size property doesn't seem to be working in Chrome or Safari.

```css
div {
    width: 161px;
    height: 149px;
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_HGPPifzMEZU/Rw4ujF12G3I/AAAAAAAAAWI/bc1ppSb6eKA/s320/estrelas_09.gif) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
    -web-kit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in
}
div:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
hey
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ubcka/14/

Comment: As of right now, the fiddle seems to work in Chrome 31.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should check the browser version and whether it supports both `background-size` and `transition`.  If the former, but not the latter use:

```
transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-ms-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-o-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
```

Comment: The prefixes were there in his original question and his fiddles. I'm not sure why he removed them.

Comment: don't forget `-ms-transition:` (for IE10 coming up)

Comment: Thanks. I guess animating background-size is only supported in firefox

Comment: @JayC It's added and thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @j-man86: What do you mean you "guess animating background-size is only supported in firefox"?  Note that in you post and fiddle you have `-web-kit-` which should be `-webkit-`.

Comment: I've seen better results using `background` (without -size) as the property.

Answer (score 23):

It's not widely supported. See a complete list of CSS properties that support transition [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties). I would have a different approach. Wrap your element with `background-color` you wanted to do transition to, and do a scale transition for your element.

```
<div class="your-wrapper">
  <div class="your-div">

  </div>   
</div>
```

also make sure to add proper styling

```
.your-wrapper {
   overflow:hidden
}
.your-div {
   transition: transform 0.5s; 
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s
}
.your-wrapper:hover .your-div{
   transform: scale(1.5); -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

This should do.

Comment: hey, funny, and youre right. it works in webkit, though.

Comment: Actually, that specification doesn't seem to be up to date. background-size does support animation, at least in Firefox. More detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23386830/1816603

Comment: Well, my solution is cross-browser, at least with any modern browser HTML5, IE9+.

Answer (score 17):

you need to set the background-size on the div otherwise it dosn't have a set size to animate from.

```
.div { 
 background-size: 100%; //set the original size!!!!!!!!!!!!
-webkit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
}

.div:hover { 
 background-size: 110%; 
}
```

Comment: Yes this is true. Even setting `background-size: cover` on the div won't work. It must be a numerical value

Answer (score 8):

You just need to change:

```
-web-kit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
```

to:

```
-webkit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `-web-kit-` to `-webkit-`.

Also, you should write original CSS property after properties with a vendor-prefix (it's very important). Otherwise, if browser has implemented that CSS3 property (like `transition`), then original property will be replaced by property with vendor-prefix — and that is not good.

**WRONG order:**

```
transition: ...;
-webkit-transition: ...;
```

**RIGHT order:**

```
-webkit-transition: ...;
transition: ...;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also just change all the transition declarations to read like this (it's not the background but the background-size that is changing:

```
transition: background-size .4s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: thanks fordareh, but that still does not produce any animation

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a old question, but using "all" works fine for me.

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
```

Comment: Well this was a browser support issue, not about the syntax, even though your answer should work, it's not really specific enough

Comment: I know that is not specific at all but it's an alternative that never let me down .