# CSS Background image size transition

Tags: css, background, hover, transition

I am working on a simple markup with resizing a div's background img.
See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zeYZL/

I need this to be animated with a simple CSS transition.
and I tried doing this:

```
#tile:hover {
    background-size:550px 550px;
    background-position:-50px -50px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;

}
```

But then the background image clips upon the hover. (See http://jsfiddle.net/5Hm9u/)

Any tips on how to fix it?

Greetings, Chris

Comment: For some reason stackoverflow doesn't allow me to greet you all

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hm9u/1/)

You need to put `background` properties outside the `hover` too, so it knows what to return to when not on hover.

e.g.

```
.tile{
  float:left;
  margin:1px;
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-size:450px 450px;
  background-position:0px 0px;
}
```

And if you want it to transition on mouseover and when you take the mouse off, you put the transition on `.tile` and not `.tile:hover`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hm9u/2/)

**Side note**

You should avoid using inline styles where you can use a stylesheet.
Put your background image in `.tile` rather than using the `style` attribute.

Full CSS:

```
.tile{
  float:left;
  margin:1px;
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-size:450px 450px;
  background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/450x450);
  background-position:0px 0px;
  transition:all 0.5s ;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-size:550px 550px;
  background-position:-50px -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have inline CSS which should be extracted to the initial CSS state.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zeYZL/1/)

```
.tile{
    float:left;
    margin:1px;
    width:450px;
    height:450px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/450x450);
    -webkit-background-size: 450px;
    background-size: ;
    background-position: center;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;

}
.tile:hover {
    background-size:550px 550px;

}
```