# Delay Hover effect on background-size in CSS

Tags: css, hover, delay, background-size

I wonder if there is a way to delay the hover effect on background-size that goes from "cover" to "contain"?  I have seen transition-delay works on backround-color and other properties but not backround-size.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0s background-size;
    transition-delay:1s;
}
div:hover{
    background-size: contain;
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtku7sqk/

**UPDATE**
Perhaps I should clarify that I want to delay the hover effect to happen but not extend the duration of the animation.

Similar to this... 
http://dabblet.com/gist/1498443

---

**LATEST UPDATE**

I figure out a way to fix this by using a mix of both CSS and javascript.

**This way "background-size" works with "contain" and "cover"**

```
$("#tmp").hover(function() {

    /* Mouse enter */
    var thisone = $(this);
    window.mytimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        thisone.addClass("mouseon");
    }, 1000);

}, function() {

    /* Mouse leave */
    clearTimeout(window.mytimeout);
    $(this).removeClass("mouseon");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtku7sqk/5/

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947683/css3-background-size-transition-animation-in-webkit-doesnt-work-bug-or-wron

Comment: Tried adding the following, still doesn't work with background-size. 

<pre>
    transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;    
    transition:-delay 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
</pre>

Comment: Ok, just remembered seeing it and thought it might help! Sorry it didn't work!  Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's only one small little thing with your CSS, otherwise it'll work exactly as you expect.

**You can't transition from non-numerical values**

The values `contain` and `cover` for `background-size` aren't transition-able.  Since they're non-numerical, you can't operate a CSS calculation on them.

If you change that to a numerical value like in the example below, it'll happen exactly how you expect it to:

## [Fiddle illustrating this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtku7sqk/3/)

Here are the changes to the CSS:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
    background-size: 100%; /* NOT `cover` anymore */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0s background-size;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
div:hover{
    background-size: 20%; /* NOT `contain` anymore */
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying jQuery animate function? Without putting an extremely amount of effort, I think this is a good start for your problem. And of course, you can modify as you wish.

note: I understand you requested CSS but in this case, JQuery would be your best bet. However, if you are only requesting CSS, disregard this response. But I posted it because future visitors may be able to use this method and not have your restrictions. Cheers!

```
$( "div ").hover(function() {
    $( "img" ).animate({
      width: "100%",
    }, 1500 );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EajEJP)

Comment: I actually want to delay the hover effect to happen, but not delay the duration of animation. 

Similar to this... instead of delaying the background color change to happen, I want to delay background-size to go from cover to contain. 

http://dabblet.com/gist/1498443

Comment: Thanks Lotusms anyway

Comment: No problem. My apologies. If I get some time later on I'll revisit this. Unless someone else got to it. Happy Thanksgiving

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

---

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nox7cgc1/)**

---

If you want to work *transition* should use background-position with px something like:

```
div{
   background-position: 0px 0px;
}
div:hover{
   background-position: center center;
}
```